# Unable to add my micro service as Eureka Client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have set a sample Micro Service using 3 spring boot applications. Post that I am trying to connect all of them to Eureka Server.
There are 3 spring Boot Applications Task-Display,Task-Repo and Task-Status-Repo. 
Task Display communicates with the other two and retrieve data.

Now Problem is except Task-Display all others are linked to eureka server. Getting the following error when Task Display is deployed

```
2019-08-31 18:43:00.055  INFO 15528 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_TASK-DISPLAY- 
ME;/192.168.1.9:task-display-me;:8180 - Re-registering apps/TASK-DISPLAY- 
ME;
2019-08-31 18:43:00.055  INFO 15528 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_TASK-DISPLAY- 
ME;/192.168.1.9:task-display-me;:8180: registering service...
2019-08-31 18:43:00.057  WARN 15528 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with 
status code 400; retrying on another server if available
2019-08-31 18:43:00.059  WARN 15528 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with 
status code 400; retrying on another server if available
2019-08-31 18:43:00.060  WARN 15528 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] 
com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_TASK-DISPLAY- 
ME;/192.168.1.9:task-display-me;:8180 - registration failed Cannot execute 
request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute 
request on any known server
```

This is my Application.java of the server which is not getting linked to Eureka

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class TaskDisplayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskDisplayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your configurations you should point to discovery server, make sure it was registered.

Comment: Could you please elobrate on this process as I am completely new to this. Btw I have already tried Eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = (my Eureka server address)

Comment: Put `@EnableDiscoveryClient` instead of `@EnableEurekaClient`

Comment: I didnt work with DiscoveryClient too

Comment: please clone and follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/ and let know if it works, this can help you

Comment: Appreciate your help :) The example has one service . When I run my application using 2 services, it works perfectly fine. The problem is with this Task-Display boot app only. Even I tried pasting the pom.xml file of the working one. Am I missing any configurations or any priorities need to be set?

Comment: can you share your application.properties file?